# A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. Returning a value from subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

How it possible to return a value from subscribe? Below code throws exception

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

```ts
getNotificationType(_activatedRouter: ActivatedRoute):Observable<number>{
  _activatedRouter.params.subscribe(params => {
      const menuId = params['id'];
      if (menuId) {
         return this.masterDataService.getNotTypeByMenu(menuId).subscribe(res => {
             if (res){
              return res.notificationType; 
             }
          })
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's not, subscribe is the end of the chain. But the specific error is because you say your function will return an observable, but don't return anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: It is not possible, since you are dealing with async operations.
One way to help you would be to asign the value to a field of your class inside the subscription and make your function of type void.

You seem to have a misunderstanding about Observables.
The Observable return type of your function does mean, that you need to return something that can be subscribed to, not the emitted value of your subscription.

If you do want to get the number in question you should first of all avoid subscribing to an observable inside an subsccription, since that is the perfect source for extensive memory leak. Maybe look into something like `switchmap`. Your code might first of all be changed into something like:

```
getNotificationType$(_activatedRouter: ActivatedRoute):Observable<number>{
   return _activatedRouter.params.pipe(
      switchmap(params => {
          const menuId = params['id'];
          if (menuId) {
             return this.masterDataService.getNotTypeByMenu(menuId);
          } else {
             throwError() // or whatever you need to do in your specific case possibly include a catch
          }
      }));
}
```

Since you are working with Observables it is best to subscribe as few times as humanly possible, since that eases your cleanup in the end.

For your specific case it would be helpful to know how you are using the number your want to receive.

- Is it fetched after it was already loaded before? ==> [ShareReplay](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/shareReplay)
- Is it displayed in your template? ==> [Async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)
  ...

Would you be so kind to share your specific use so we can tailor a specific solution for you?